How to estimate thermal conductivity of a sample?
There is a rectangular sample whose emissivity is known, and I want to estimate its thermal conductivity. A heater with a known heat flux is applied to one end of the sample and a fixed temperature is applied to the other end. If two sections are selected along the direction of heat transfer (As shown in the figure) and the heat flux and temperature passing through both sections are known, can the thermal conductivity of the sample be obtained from these conditions? (We also need to take into account the heat radiation loss, we know the ambient temperature, and the environment is a vacuum so we don't consider convection)

I used COMSOL to do the simulation (the function is steady-state). I wanted to use the temperature gradient and net heat flow from the total heat flow into the material minus the radiation loss to get the thermal conductivity, but the results were not accurate. I later found that using the heat flux in the middle of the material to calculate the thermal conductivity was very accurate (perhaps because I set the temperature probe to be symmetrical along the midpoint of the material?).
May I ask why? Is there a formula or theory to support it?

The net heat should be equal to the temperature difference divided by the conductance ($Q=\Delta T/G$). Then you need to rely the conductance to the conductivity through geometrical arguments. If you have access to the heat current density, then you do not need the geometrical arguments.

yes, I think so. Maybe my problem is about the COMSOL, I do not understand the simulation process

try Matter Modeling SE

thank you very much

We can expect the findings you observed because the heat flux at any point depends on conduction and radiation (and thus depends on the position, emissivity, thermal conductivity, and surrounding temperature), whereas the heat flux per temperature gradient at any interior point depends only on the thermal conductivity, per Fourier's law.
To back out the thermal conductivity from the heat flux alone, one needs to solve the heat equation within the material for the entire problem.
Let's consider an example: Idealize the material as long and narrow, to permit a 1-D approximation in the $x$-direction. A steady-state energy balance of any slice of the material yields
$$kA\frac{d^2 T(x)}{dx^2}=\sigma\varepsilon P [T(x)^4-T_\infty^4],$$
with thermal conductivity $k$, cross-sectional area $A$, temperature $T$, Stefan–Boltzmann constant $\sigma$, emissivity $\varepsilon$, perimeter length $P$ (=$2A/r$ for a circular cross section with radius $r$) and surrounding enclosure temperature $T_\infty$. That is, the conduction input balances the radiation output.
This nonlinear PDE would need to be solved numerically. If $T(x)$ isn't much different from $T_\infty$, though, we can linearize the radiation term as approximation $4T_\infty^3 T^\prime(x)$, where $T^\prime(x)=T(x)-T_\infty$. With this approximation, we have a linear PDE:
$$\frac{d^2 T^\prime(x)}{dx^2}-C_1T^\prime(x)=0,$$
where $C_1=\frac{4\sigma\varepsilon PT_\infty^3}{kA},$ with solution
$$T^\prime(x)=C_2\sinh\left(\sqrt{C_1}x\right)+C_3\cosh\left(\sqrt{C_1}x\right)$$
subject to boundary conditions $\left.\frac{dT^\prime(x)}{dx}\right|_0=\frac{q_\mathrm{left}}{k}$ and $T^\prime(x)|_L=T_\mathrm{right}-T_\infty$ (with length $L$), so
$$T(x)=T_\infty+\frac{q}{k\sqrt{C_1}}\sinh(\sqrt{C_1}x)+\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{C_1}L)}\left(T_\mathrm{right}-T_\infty-\frac{q}{k\sqrt{C_1}}\sinh(\sqrt{C_1}L)\right)\cosh(\sqrt{C_1}x),$$
from which one could back out the thermal conductivity if they knew the temperature and the other material properties.
Clearly, multiple assumptions and idealizations have been needed here to obtain a closed-form expression, but I hope this clarifies why the thermal conductivity isn't straightforwardly linked with the temperature $T$ or temperature gradient $\nabla T$ alone but is straightforwardly linked with the conductive heat flux $-k\nabla T$ per unit gradient $\nabla T$, again per Fourier's law.

Thank you for your answer, I did realize later that the temperature of the sample surface was not linear, so my initial method was wrong, and the subsequent coincidence may mean that the ratio of the difference between the two temperatures and the distance may be close to the temperature gradient value in the middle of the sample, so using the heat flux in the middle of the sample can get a relatively accurate thermal conductivity.

and I failed to solve this nonlinear PDE :), maybe I will use the numerical method later.
